# Breaking string into sentences in java (after symbol of specified group occurs)

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, string, text

So I wrote the following code:

```
String text = "This is a string.        I want to break it into sentences";
String[] sentences = text.split("\\."); 

for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++)
    System.out.println(sentences[i]);
```

The output of this code is:

```
This is a string
        I want to break it into sentences
```

How do I change this code so that

1. Each new sentence will be created not only after ".", but also after "!" or "?".
2. There won't be any spaces in the beginning of sentence.

For example, if we have the following string

```
String text = "This is a string!   Is this a string?         I want to break it into sentences";
```

then the output should be:

```
This is a string
Is this a string
I want to break it into sentences
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the delimiters inside a character class and add `\\s*` next to the char class so that it would consume also the following zero or more spaces.

```
String[] sentences = text.split("[?!.]\\s*");
```

**Example:**

```
String text = "This is a string!   Is this a string?         I want to break it into sentences";
String[] parts = text.split("[?!.]\\s*"); 
for(String i: parts)
{
System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Output:**

```
This is a string
Is this a string
I want to break it into sentences
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Could you also tell me how to get the same output as in your example when I have "?!" or "???", "!!!", "..." etc. in the end of sentence?

Comment: make the char class to repeat one or more times by adding `+` quantifier next to the char class like `String[] sentences = text.split("[?!.]+\\s*"); `

Answer (score 1):

You can use a character class to split around either one of the dot (`.`), `?` or `!` characters. To remove the space at the beginning (and possibly at the end) of the sentence, you can simply trim the resulting string:

```
String[] sentences = text.split("[.!?]");

for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(sentences[i].trim());
}
```